# I use xcode8 archive the App run well on iOS 11,But xcode9 GM archive the App show more different

Tags: xcode, ios11

I use xcode8 archive the App run well on iOS 11,But xcode9 GM archive the App show more different.
For example, UINavigationBar show different but the code same!
Who can tell me why and how fix it?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Xcode 8 to build the app its using iOS 10..so the UINavigationBar you are watching is from iOS 10..So even you are running on iOS 11 its using iOS 10 UINavigationBar.But when u are building with Xcode 9 its using iOS 11 sdk. So its changing as iOS 11 behaviour.. Actually it depends on which sdk u are using.

Comment: So.If user's iphone upgrade iOS11,it well run well.The App on AppStore build by Xcode8 . Is it right?

Comment: you are wellcome